# How can I call a local image using props in another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have defined my constructor here in **HomeProduct.js** file:

```
class HomeProduct {
  constructor(id, title, image) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.image = image;
  }
}

export default HomeProduct;
```

Now, here is my **home-dummy-data.js** file

```
import HomeProduct from "../models/HomeProduct";

const HOMEPRODUCTS = [
  new HomeProduct(
    "hp1",
    "Fruits",
    require("../assets/my-apps-images/apples.jpg")
  ),
  new HomeProduct(
    "hp2",
    "Vegetables",
    require("../assets/my-apps-images/guava.jpg")
  ),
```

Now, here is my final file where I am rendering the images:

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet, Button } from "react-native";

const ProductItem = props => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.product}>
      <Image style={styles.image} source={props.image} />
    ...
```

The image is being rendered but the warning says that the Failed Prop types, please see the attachement.
[image][image]

Comment: What propType do you have defined for `source`?

Answer (score 0):

[According to the React Native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images#source-as-an-object): `source` takes in an object with an `uri` attribute.

If we adapt it to your code it would be:

```
<Image style={styles.image} source={{ uri: props.image }} />
```

That should resolve the warning.

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like this:

```
<Image style={styles.image} source={require('path to file')} />
```